# NSData dataWithContentsOfURL are null after update Xcode 6.4 to Xcode 7.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, nsdata

Before I update Xcode version 6.4 it still work fine.

here is my code

```
 - (NSArray*)getData{
NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
    NSString *path = @"http://rmfl.nagasoftware.com/api/plant_by_season.php?lang_code=1&season_id=0";

    if(path){
     NSLog(@"%@",path);
        NSURL *json = [NSURL URLWithString:path]; // jsonString
         NSLog(@"URL is %@",[json absoluteString]);
        NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:json];
```

Here is the link to see the image from the NSLog.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you also updated to iOS 9, if so that is the problem.

See: [App Transport Security Technote](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/index.html)

The solution is to up date the server to https TLS 1.2 and forward security.

Another solution is to whitelist the url on the app plist or even if necessary allow all http connections. This reduces the connection security, the best approach is to update the server.

Comment: I'm just curious how XCode `6.x` would still work for them? I guess we don't really know how they are running the code either (simulator, or real device). Good answer anyway +1

Comment: What is the targerf iOS version in your Xcode 7.x? The new rules only apply if the target is iOS 9 and the version on the device is also iOS 9 (and above of course).

Comment: Well, I think they need to tell you that :) As I understand though `OS X` 10.11 will also have the change you mentioned.

Comment: There was the [WWDC 2015 session 706](http://asciiwwdc.com/2015/sessions/706) that described as well as the release notes: [What's New in iOS iOS 9.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016198-SW1). I believe it was also mentioned in the WWDC keynote.

Comment: Yes, 10.11 will also support App Transport Security (ATS).

Comment: @zaph Thanks for your clear answer. Now I can solve this problem.